# How to run spyder 3 in new environment?

Tags: python, linux, environment-variables, anaconda, spyder

The linux server that I'm working on has python 2.7.13.
I created a new environment (new_env) and after running "source activate new_env", have installed anaconda3 on it. 
Now still get into spyder with ptython IDE 2.7.13. How I can run spyder with python 3?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

> How I can run spyder with python 3?

After activating your environment, you just need to execute the following command in the terminal:

`spyder`

Comment: but it brings me to spyder 3 with python 2.7 which is the default python on my server.

Comment: I tried to run spyder from the anaconda3\bin directory and now it worked, however the screen is black and it does not run correctly